# Embedded null-homologous circle in high dimension is bound by disc

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cobordism

Assume we have an oriented manifold $M$ of dimension say $n > 2$ (or if necessary $n > 3$) and an embedded circle $S$ whose fundamental class $[S]$ is zero in homology. Is that circle always the boundary of an embedded disc?

In dimension 2, there is the counter-example taking a 2-genus surface and the circle splitting the 2-genus into two 1-genus surfaces with boundary. This seems to work here because of an Jordan-curve-like argument. I wonder whether this might change in higher dimensions.

Counter-examples or proof-sketches/references are pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first obstruction is given by thinking of the circle $S$ as being an element of the fundamental group. A necessary requirement that $[S]$ bounds an embedded disk is that $[S]=0 \in \pi_1(M)$. This is very much going to be false in general.

If, however, you know that $[S]=0$ in the fundamental group, if the dimension of $M \geq 5$, then the answer is yes. This follows from the following form of the
Whitney embedding theorem: If $X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of smooth manifolds such that $2\operatorname{dim}(X)+1 \leq \operatorname{dim}(Y)$, then it is homotopic to an embedding.

We apply this theorem to the map $D^2 \rightarrow M$ guaranteed by the fact $[S]=0$ in the fundamental group to get the embedded disk you ask for.

Comment: I was afraid that's not gonna work. Do you have an explicit counter-example?

Comment: Your example is a fundamental example. The circle you pick is of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ in the fundamental group and this is nontrivial. If you want higher dimensional examples, take any manifold and cross it with this surface. Since the fundamental group commutes with products, you will still have an example. More generally, if you have any manifold with a fundamental group with nontrivial commutator, all the elements of the commutator give examples, provided the dimension is 3 or above.

Comment: This is because we can apply the Whitney embedding theorem to show every element of the fundamental group is represented by an embedding.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly the answer I was seeking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @YoungMath I don't know if the bound of dimension 5 is best possible; it certainly can't be 3 since knot theory exists. I recall reading a comment of Milnor saying that he did not know if codimension 2 maps into 4 manifolds had the Whitney embedding property.

Comment: Interesting. Do you remember where you caught that comment?

Comment: @YoungMath "A procedure for killing homotopy groups of differentiable manifolds" right after lemma 6.